# How to decode (non-standard) alphanumeric SMS Sender ID?

Tags: mobile, sms, sms-gateway

I'm receiving text messages (SMS) via GSM modem and processing them automatically with a custom script. **How do I decode an *alphanumeric* sender ID?**

Example:

```
Sender ID = +6;91<06130
```

...which should read "Holvi" (if I'm not mistaken).

I guess there is something like a translation table which converts this number to an alphanumeric string.

```
6; = H
91 = o
<0 = l
61 = v
30 = i
```

So far, so good. Sadly I cannot find any information about this special encoding. Also, I could not find any relation to a standard ASCII table (maybe special characters like `;` or `<` could be substitutes for hexadecimal `a-f`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How do you read the message ? Is it already somehow decoded for this output ?
Alphanumeric sender number are usually by SMS standard GSM7 encoded, for example, "Halvi" would be in hex format: 0AC837DB9E06

Comment: I know about GSM7, however I could not find any match on byte distances between these two encodings. The number is retrieved via REST API from the SMS gateway. It already comes like this.

Comment: Then you must check with SMS gateway documentation. Which gateway is it ?

Comment: Already checked documentation and contacted vendor, without any success. I use Teltonika RUT 9xx model.

Comment: I very much believe, that this gateway does not support Alphanumeric senders, that's why it shows junk :(

Comment: You could be right. But it doesn't explain the chunk in any way - at least they must have made some effort to transcode something. I try contacting the vendor again... Thank you though.